# Problema con mi web en la nube

Tags: php, mysql, servidor, php7

estoy teniendo problema al hacer consultas desde mi web a la base de datos ya todo estando en la nuebe, pero localmente si funciona.

bueno he subido mi web a 000webhosting y pues yo al abrir un archivo que es mi webservices para que me muestre algunos datos, pues no me los muestra pero localmente en mi xampp si me muestra aqui esta el archivo que esta subido al servidor llamado: ExtraerSucursales.php

```
       $host_name = "localhost";
        $database = " id7358362_gestion_de_clientes";
        $user = "id7358362_root";
        $password = "LA_COntra de la base de datos";

       $json = array();


      $conexion = mysqli_connect($host_name,$user,$password,$database);
      $consulta = "select latitud,longitud from sucursal";

      $resultado_consulta = mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta);

       if($resultado_consulta){

         while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado_consulta)){

       $json["sucursales"][] = $fila;
       }

        echo json_encode($json);
        }
```

ahora al abrir ese archivo deberia imprimirme datos en formato json pero no imprime nada queda blanco, obviamente ya que he creado la base de datos con los parametros q mostre arriba etc etc , ahora no se si sea el localhost o nose pero porfavor necesito que puedan ayudarme si necesitan q muestre algo se lo puestro gracias. :).

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! donde creaste la base de datos? porque vas a tener que modificar los parametros para que accedan a la nueva base de datos.

Comment: holaa @gbianchi gracias por todo. Puej la cree en phpmyadmin y la subi a 000webhosting

Comment: Como que la subiste? el servicio de hosting ese, te ofrece una base de datos y un acceso a la misma?

Answer (score 0):

puedes intentar con esto:

```
$conexion = @mysqli_connect($host_name,$user,$password,$database);
if(!$conexion){
die('Error de conexión: ' . mysqli_connect_error() . 'or ' . mysqli_errno() . ' or' . mysqli_error() );
}
```